# A singular value-eigenvalue inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ra.rings-and-algebras, inequalities, matrix-analysis

Singular value or eigenvalue problems lie at the center of matrix analysis. One classical result is

$$\lambda_{j}(X^{*}X+Y^{*}Y)\geq 2\sigma_j(XY^*)$$

for $j \in \{1, \ldots, n\}$, where $\lambda_j(\cdot)$ and $\sigma_j(\cdot)$ denote the $j$th largest eigenvalue and singular value, respectively, and $X$ and $Y$ are $n \times n$ complex matrices. I conjecture that the following does hold.

$$\lambda_{j}((I+X^{*}X)(I+Y^{*}Y))\geq\sigma_j^2(I+XY^*)$$

Comment: I've done some numerical tests in n=4 with no counterexamples yet. I prefer the following form of the question: $\lambda_j((I + X^*X)(I+ Y^*Y)) \geq \lambda_j((I+YX^*)(I+XY^*))$?

Comment: Thanks. Let us see if that form has any advantage in a possible "proof ".

Comment: Is it known that $\lambda_j(X^*X Y^*Y) \geq \lambda_j(YX^* XY^*)$ ?

Comment: @jjcale Yes, by similarity when $Y$ is invertible and then the general case by continuity.

Comment: @jjcale it is equality... the nonzero eigenvalues of $MN$ coincide with those of $NM$.

Comment: @M. Lin So your inequality is "asymptotical true" if $X$ and $Y$ are both large and also if both are small since $\lambda_j(X^*X + Y^*Y) \geq \lambda_j(YX^* + XY^*)$ .

Comment: @M.Lin I'm blanking on the proof of the "classical result". Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: @ChrisRamsey It first appears in this paper http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/0611018

Comment: Equivalent : $\lambda_j(A B^{-1} + B + A) \geq \lambda_j(2A^{1/2} + A)$ for hermitian positive definite $A$ and $B$ :
Choose $Z = XY^*$, $A=Z^* Z$, $B=YY^*$ .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The conjecture is true.

**Lemma 1** : For every matrix $Z$ holds $\lambda_j(Z^* Z + Z^* + Z ) \leq \lambda_j(Z^* Z + 2 (Z^* Z)^{1/2})$ .

For a proof see the proof of  $\lambda_j(Z^* + Z ) \leq \lambda_j(2 (Z^* Z)^{1/2})$ in Bhatia, Matrix Analysis, Proposition III.5.1 (Fan-Hoffman).

**Lemma 2** : For $a \geq 0 , b > 0$ holds $(a+b)(1+b^{-1}) \geq a + 2 a^{1/2} + 1$ .

Proof left to the reader.

**Proof of the conjecture :**

Choose $Z = XY^*$, $A=Z^* Z$, $B=YY^*$ .

We may assume that $B$ is invertable.

Then we have to show :

$\lambda_j((I+B^{-1})^{1/2}(A+B)(I+B^{-1})^{1/2}) \geq \lambda_j(A + 2A^{1/2} + I)$ .

Let $V_j$ be the span of the eigenvectors to the j largest eigenvalues of $A$ and $W_j = (I+B^{-1})^{-1/2}(V_j)$ .

Then

$\lambda_j((I+B^{-1})^{1/2}(A+B)(I+B^{-1})^{1/2})$
$ \geq min \{x^* ((I+B^{-1})^{1/2}(A+B)(I+B^{-1})^{1/2})x : x \in W_j$ and  $x^* x = 1\}$
$\geq min \{x^* ((I+B^{-1})^{1/2}(\lambda_j(A)I+B)(I+B^{-1})^{1/2})x : x \in W_j$ and  $x^* x = 1\}$
$\geq \lambda_j(A) + 2 \lambda_j(A)^{1/2} + 1 = \lambda_j(A + 2A^{1/2} + I)$ .

Comment: Nice proof! Thanks. I think this inequality is of independent interest. Are you interested in exploring the possible use of this result with me? As I don't know your real name, you are more than welcome to contact me... m_lin@i.shu.edu.cn